# How to replace multiple blanks with one blank and keep all blanks both on beginning and end unchanged with awk quickly?

Tags: awk

Input string

```
"   x1    x2    x3       x4   "
```

Expected string

```
"   x1 x2 x3 x4   "
```

To replace multi blanks with one blank and keep all blanks both on beginning and end with awk.

It is my try.

```
echo "   x1    x2    x3       x4   " |awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "}{$1=$1;print $0}'
```

All multiple blanks repalced with one blank,but all blanks both on beginning and end deleted too.
How to convert the string  quickly with awk?
1. replace multiple blanks with one blank
2. keep all blanks both on beginning and end

**sed 's/\b +\b/ /g'** can do the trick.

```
echo "   x1    x2    x3       x4   " | sed 's/\b \+\b/ /g'
```

To make it clear.

```
echo "|$(echo "   x1    x2    x3       x4   " | sed 's/\b \+\b/ /g')|"
|   x1 x2 x3 x4   |
```

The reg expression  /\b +\b/  can't be used in awk.

```
echo "   x1    x2    x3       x4   " | awk '{gsub(/\b \+\b/," ");print}'
echo "   x1    x2    x3       x4   " | awk '{gsub(/\b +\b/," ");print}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to use the right identifier:

```
echo "|$(echo "   x1    x2    x3       x4   " | awk 'gsub(/\y +\y/," ")')|"
```

I put in the extra echo just to show the additional spaces are still there

Comment: Remember `\y` is `gawk` specific construct, ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gawk-3.0.3/html_chapter/gawk_5.html, `++` for the right approach

Answer (score 1):

@try:

```
awk '{match($0,/^\" +/);val1=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);match($0,/ +\"$/);val2=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,FS);gsub(/\" /,val1);gsub(/ \"$/,val2);print}'  Input_file
```

Will add the code explanation shortly too.

**EDIT:**

```
awk '{
        match($0,/^\" +/);              #### Using match keyword for finding the starting " till first space.
        val1=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); #### creating val1 variable and saving that above match's value into it(where RSTART and RLENGTH are awk's default variable which will be set only when a match is found.)
        match($0,/ +\"$/);              #### Using match keyword for finding the space till string " end of the line.
        val2=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); #### creating val2 variable and saving that above match's value into it(where RSTART and RLENGTH are awk's default variable which will be set only when a match is found.)
        gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,FS);        #### global substitution of space for whole spaces with a single space in complete record/line.
        gsub(/\" /,val1);               #### Now substituting the match of starting with " till space with variable val1.
        gsub(/ \"$/,val2);              #### Now substituting the match of starting with " till space with variable val2.
        print                           #### print the current line.
     }
    '  Input_file                       #### Mentioning Input_file here.
```

Comment: It is no need to use **match($0,/^\" +/); **,the primitive input is echo "   x1    x2    x3       x4   " not echo  '"   x1    x2    x3       x4   "',**match($0,/^ +/); ** is ok .

Answer (score 0):

For grail's answer.

```
sudo apt-get install gawk
echo "   x1    x2    x3       x4   " | awk 'gsub(/\y +\y/," ")'
```

To make it more clear with the below.

```
echo "|$(echo "   x1    x2    x3       x4   " | awk 'gsub(/\y +\y/," ")')|"
```

Comment: To add | at the beginning and end  is to make the blank at the beginning and end more clear.

Comment: I have noticed this.

Comment: It is no need to use **match($0,/^\" +/); **,the primitive input is echo " x1 x2 x3 x4 " not echo '" x1 x2 x3 x4 "',**match($0,/^ +/); **